# Comparar una cadena con una lista e imprimir el mas similar

Tags: python, string

Buen dia, Estoy buscando la forma de poder comparar dos cadenas similares y me dea el mas parecido, Por ejemplo.

```
s1 = ["una-cadena-Similar",
      "cadena-ssimilar",
      "similar cadenaaa"]

s2 = "Una-cadena-similarr"
```

de esa lista me imprima el mas similar que seria `"una-cadena-Similar"`, El `==` solo me imprime si son completamente iguales y el `in` tampoco me funcionó, Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias!

Comment: Primero tienes que definir "similtud".

Comment: Se refiere a que tanto se parece cada palabra de la lista a una especifica, o eso interpreté.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el modulo `hermetrics`. Es un modulo externo, así que tendrías que instalarlo con pip.
Una vez tengas instalado el modulo, puedes obtener la palabra más similar de la siguiente forma:

```
s1 = ["una-cadena-Similar",
      "cadena-ssimilar",
      "similar cadenaaa"]

s2 = "Una-cadena-similarr"


from hermetrics.hamming import Hamming

ham = Hamming()
print(max(s1, key=lambda cadena:ham.similarity(cadena, s2)))
```

Comment: una pregunta por favor,,,, si los datos en la lista estuvieran separados por comillas simples, funcionaría?,,, a mi me da algún fallo. Y si fuera así, cómo puedo cambiar comillas dobles por simples?. Muchas gracias